# radial progress transition when altered

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://codepen.io/geedmo/pen/InFfd

I tried to add   `transition: width .6s ease` to `.progress-radial` but it doesn't seem work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyframes.
good documention : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp